# Are traditional IRAs worse than taxable brokerage accounts at high incomes?

Tags: united-states, ira, capital-gains-tax

Brokerage accounts are seen as relatively tax-inefficient, since you invest with post-tax dollars, and growth is taxed upon realizing gains. The traditional IRA allows you to deduct contributions and defer taxes until you take distributions in retirement ...

Unless you are covered by a retirement plan from work and make over

- $71,000/year if single, or
- $118,000/year if married filing jointly.

The numbers above come from [a table published by the IRS for the 2015 tax year](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/2015-IRA-Deduction-Limits-Effect-of-Modified-AGI-on-Deduction-if-You-Are-Covered-by-a-Retirement-Plan-at-Work). Above those thresholds, you can still make contributions to a traditional IRA, but those contributions will be post-tax. Distributions are taxed as ordinary income, excluding post-tax principal.

Similarly, eligibility to make direct Roth IRA contributions phases out to zero according to a [different table](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Amount-of-Roth-IRA-Contributions-That-You-Can-Make-For-2015):

- $131,000 if single, or
- $193,000 if married filing jointly.

Looks to me that someone who cannot make direct Roth IRA contributions also cannot deduct traditional IRA deposits from income.

Assume

- investment period is 20 years,
- is some garden variety ETF (VTI/VXUS/etc),
- those investments return 5%,
- the current marginal tax rate is 28%,
- the expected marginal tax rate at retirement is 25%,
- the long term capital gains rate is 15%,
- the entity is not eligible to make Roth IRA contributions, and
- 401k contributions are already maxed out.

A $5000 of gross income contribution into a traditional IRA at retirement might grow to an after-tax sum of:

```
(5000) * (1 - 0.28) * (1 + (1.05 ** 20 - 1) * (1 - 0.25)) = $8064
```

Instead, since contributions were going to be taxed anyway, why not put it in a brokerage account? Then you could claim the favorable long-term capital gains rate.

```
(5000) * (1 - 0.28) * (1 + (1.05 ** 20 - 1) * (1 - 0.15)) = $8659
```

All I found was [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/11089/any-advantage-to-non-deductible-traditional-ira-contibutions), and the accepted answer says to still make a traditional IRA contribution, but I still don't see why that would be a good idea. What am I missing here?

Comment: The answer on that question mentions conversion.  It doesn't go into detail but I assume the idea is to do a so-called "back door" conversion which allows you get a Roth despite the income limits.  Withdrawals would then be tax free.  Perhaps @JoeTaxpayer can provide more detail on his answer.

Comment: Your calculation is incorrect because taxes on non-deductible traditional IRA withdrawals consider your basis to prevent double taxation. More details [here](https://www.bogleheads.org/wiki/Non-deductible_traditional_IRA).

Comment: Doesn't my calculation take the after tax contribution to the non deductible traditional IRA as the tax basis?

Comment: Yeah I guess it does, after taking a closer look. But another thing to keep in mind is an ETF like VTI or VXUS will pay out dividends, which will be shielded from taxes along the way in an IRA versus a taxable account.

Comment: That much is absolutely true. Perhaps relatively tax efficient funds like VTI won't cause as much drag compare to tax inefficient ones, like REITs or taxable bond funds, where the tax shield of the IRA will provide more benefit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your scenario (which here I won't debate, but just apply the math) is that your marginal rate is 28% when money is earned, and your rate in retirement is 25%.

Traditional IRA - you have $10,000 pretax. It grows to $100,000 and on withdrawal, you lose 25% to tax, *$75,000 net*.

Traditional IRA (no deduction) - you have $7200, same 10X return $72,000. On withdrawal, $64,800 is taxed at 25%, $16,200 tax. Net *$55,800*.

Roth IRA - you have $7200, same 10X return *$72,000 net*.

Post tax (regular broker account) - you have $7200, same 10X return $72,000 of stock and when you sell, there's $64,800 cap gain, $9,720 tax to pay, so *$62,280 net*.

Keep in mind, the phaseout for a Roth deposit is far higher than that for the IRA deduction. And the "Back Door Roth" permits a quick conversion from the non-deducted IRA to Roth, if you have no pretax IRA money. On prompting from dg99, I'll reference my article [Roth IRA Two-Step (Advanced)](http://rothmania.net/roth-ira-two-step-advanced/). It makes a few good points. First, you have one Traditional IRA. It may be spread across a dozen accounts, but it's one Individual Retirement Arrangement. It's composed (maybe) of post tax money, and pretax money. Conversions are not pick and choose, the post-tax money is pro-rated for tax purposes.

This is an oversimplification. One can run all the numbers, and make whatever assumptions you wish.

A spreadsheet will let you choose different rates for deposit, growth, and withdrawal. There's also the possibility of making an IRA deposit at a high rate, but converting to Roth somewhere along the way. It's never simple, although examples can be made so.

I agree, for this situation post tax IRA may not make sense.

Comment: Are the  IRA contributions are pretax if you cannot take the income deduction for your traditional IRA contribution?

Comment: No. Of course not.

Comment: Re: "On withdrawal, $64,800 is taxed at say, 25%, $16,200 tax. Net $55,800." Only if you're in the 25% tax bracket.  The idea is that most people will be in a lower bracket by the time they have to take RMDs from the account.

Comment: @jamesqf - the question contained "the expected marginal tax rate at retirement is 25%." - If I were writing an article, I'd go 15%, or offer multiple scenarios. In this case, I was answering the question as asked, and not debating the set-up.

Comment: The `if you have no pretax IRA money` phrase deserves a highlight or something.  If you do have pretax IRA money then mingling with post-tax becomes super annoying during back-door Roth conversions. :(

Comment: edited more. nothing is simple.

Comment: @Eric - which scenario? 28% when earned. So post tax $7200. And 25% on withdrawal, if applicable. Where do you think I messed up? I could have. I am old.

Comment: Perhaps the assumption of a stock investment increasing in value by a _factor_ of 10 without throwing off any dividends in the process is a little out of line with common experience?  (I know, I know, Apple paid no dividends for a very long time while the stock appreciated in value like crazy). My point is that a similar investment in a mutual fund, say, with yearly distributions of capital gains and dividends might look a lot different for the _(non-tax-deferred)_ brokerage account when the taxes are paid out of the distributions and only the residual amount is available for reinvestment.

Comment: Interesting. Consider, both the dividends and long term gains enjoy a 15% rate, so I played a bit fast and loose, in light of OPs wish to ignore the potential 0/10/15 rates he was insistant on ignoring.

Comment: I ran a spreadsheet, assumed a 10%/yr return, 8% appreciation 2% dividends. When approaching the 10x timeframe, this lagged the no-dividend approach by 3.5%. I agree there's a place for noting this difference, in a more comprehensive discussion on this topic. I'm still getting a grip on the fact that I am withdrawing $100k/yr from retirement funds and keeping at 15% marginal rate in retirement but OP asks us to stick with a 25% rate.

Comment: Wait, then maybe this is the bit I'm not getting. Withdrawals from traditional IRAs are taxed at the ordinary income tax rate. Let's just assume single filer 2015 numbers. My understanding is above [$37,450](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_tax_in_the_United_States#Marginal_tax_rates_for_2015), your marginal tax rate will be higher than 15% for funds being withdrawn from a traditional IRA, with no other sources of income. Is that not correct? For the hypothetical in the original question, I presumed $90k/year withdrawal rate, which puts us in the 25% marginal tax rate.

Comment: Taxable income above $37,450 is taxed at a marginal 25% for a single filer. Yes. But, with no other income, the $90K withdrawal has a $10K exemption/std deduction, and tax on $80K sees lowers rates for the money under $37K, i.e. only $43K is taxed at 25%.

Comment: All right, I'll sit down and add a bit more detail to my model. Thanks

Comment: I understand. Keep in mind, There are more than 2 points. Nearly all discussion revolves around the tax when earned and the marginal tax at withdrawal. But, any time along the way, one can convert to Roth at that year's marginal rate.